# Differentiation and counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives

If there is a function of 4 variables, there are several instances where it is said that differentiating the function with respect to one of the variables (i.e., the partial differential) is equivalent to putting a ball in the bin.  This argument is typically used to count the number of $k^{th}$ partial derivatives of a function of $m$ variables.

So, I was wondering why differentiating a function with respect to a variable is equivalent to putting a ball in the bin?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  Please provide more context illustrating a statement of the equivalence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "there are several instances where it is said that...." I'd settle for one.

Comment: The problem is that of counting the number of $k^{th}$ partial derivatives of a function of $m$ variables.

Comment: Assuming the function is regular, the order of the differentiations does not matter. So to get a $k$-th order derivative, you apply $k$ partial derivatives against various of the $m$ variables, where all that matters is how many times you differentiate with respect to each variable, not the order they were differentiated in. The individual partial derivatives are the $k$ "balls", and  the $m$ variables are the $m$ "bins" the "balls" can be put in. In both cases of derivatives and variables, and of balls in bins, we have $k$ things to distribute and $m$ choices of where to distribute them.